# How to return multiple rows matching multiple criteria in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, suppose I have rows like:

| name | team memberships |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | operations | legal |  |  |
| Kate | legal | UK residents | infrastructure | growth |
| Carlos | operations | senior management | legal |  |
| Tina | operations | UK residents | senior management |  |
| Pierre | infrastructure | operations | legal | growth |
| Amanda | UK residents | infrastructure |  |  |

**How do I get the list of people who are both UK residents, and also in infrastructure?** (The output should be the list: *Kate, Amanda*)

(For convenience, I put this on Sheets here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bNByBeM_FKuzS-MLRYOsHIP1YRs4bOH7w0c9P8b_jHs/edit?usp=sharing )

I have seen uses of `match()` and `index()`, but I can't seem to find something that lets me match logically on multiple cells within each row, while still maintaining knowledge about the rows themselves. `index(match(...))` seems to allow me to do this for a single output name, but not for a set of names.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465), like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    regexextract( 
      transpose( query( transpose(substitute(A2:F, " ", "_")), "", 9^9 ) ), 
      "(.+?) (.+)" 
    ), 
    "select Col1 
     where lower(Col2) contains 'infrastructure' 
     and lower(Col2) contains 'uk_residents' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```